# On the monotonicity of the sequence $\frac{1}{\log^2 n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> How the monotonicity of the following sequence:
>   $$
> a_n=\frac{1}{\log^2n}
> $$can be shown?

Knowing that $\log n$ is increasing, I thought that I could use the inequality $\log(n+1)>\log(n)$ but then I am not sure if I can square the inequality...

*Could you also tell me how to show the monotonicity of $a_n$ with induction or with an other way?*

Comment: As square is 1-valued increasing function for positive x, you can square both sides.

Answer (score 8):

You know that $\log(n+1)>\log(n)$. Then $$\log(n+1)\log(n+1)>\log(n)\log(n+1)>\log(n)\log(n),$$

so $\log^2(n+1)>\log^2(n).$ Taking reciprocals and remembering to reverse the inequality, we get

$$\frac{1}{\log^2(n)}>\frac{1}{\log^2(n+1)}.$$

This shows the sequence is monotonically decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac1{\log^2x}\right)'=-\frac{2}{x\log^3x}$$

and for $\; x\ge 1\;$ the above derivative is negative, so the function is monotone non-decreasing...

Answer (score 1):

In order to square an inequality, you need to make sure that both sides are positive(or at least not negative), so you know that:
$$log(n+1) > log(n)$$
$$<=> log^2(n+1) > log^2(n)$$
$$\frac{1}{log^2(n)} >\frac{1}{log^2(n+1)}$$
The denominator is increased and therefore the whole fraction is smaller.